# Concept that requires a method to have one or more arguments

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

It is quite possible that such a concept already exists but for learning more about the subject, I want to define a `runnable` concept that defines a method with an int and possibly more parameters.  I would write this way:

```
template <typename TASK, typename ...ARGS>
concept runnable = requires (TASK task, int n, ARGS... args)   {  task (n, args...);  };
```

Unfortunately, the following snippet doesn't compile:

```
#include <string>

template <typename TASK, typename ...ARGS>
concept runnable = requires (TASK task, int n, ARGS... args)   {  task (n, args...);  };

template<runnable TASK>
void run (TASK task)  {}

struct MyTask
{
    int operator() (int n, std::string x, double y) const { return 0; }
};

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    run (MyTask());
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'run'
candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with TASK = MyTask]
because 'MyTask' does not satisfy 'runnable'
because 'task(n, args...)' would be invalid: no matching function for call to object of type 'MyTask'
    task (n, args...);
```

I don't see why the `MyTask::operator()` does not fit the prototype proposed in the concept since the `requires` part should be able to cope with variadic arguments.

**Question 1** is there possible to define such a concept ?

**Question 2** if possible, what is wrong in my code ?

**UPDATE** A supplemental constraint is that `MyTask::operator()` can have has many arguments as in the example above but can't be templated. Indeed the following would work but not allowed because of this constraint:

```
struct MyTask
{
    template<typename ...ARGS>
    int operator() (int n, ARGS... args) const { return 0; }
};
```

Comment: No, not possible. You can only test if the thing is callable with specific argument types.

Comment: I think what you actually want to require is that some types operator can be called with one `int` and 0 or more other arguments. Right?

Comment: The `run` function can only possibly use a finite set of arguments to `TASK::operator()`. So the `concept` that `run` uses to constraint `TASK` should also only check this finite number of expressions. Concepts can't check a "for-all" quantification over all types or number of arguments. That's fundamentally an undecidable problem and the constraints are only supposed to make sure that the expressions used by the function are actually valid. There are no expressions that quantify over all types or all numbers of arguments.

Comment: The specific error in your shown code is that `runnable` in `template<runnable TASK>` must be given template arguments. Only the first template argument of the concept is replaced with `TASK`. The other ones are currently missing. E.g. `template<runnable<std::string, double> TASK>` would be valid and would check that `TASK::operator()` can be called with an `int`, `std::string` and then `double` argument, so that `MyTask` satisfies it.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, yes absolutely, the prototype must at least have a first argument being an int and then one can have 0 or more arguments of any type.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually wrote the following possibility. Note that I also added a constraint in the concept definition on the number of variadic parameters, just to show how to use information about the packed parameters (even if it's not useful in my real use case):

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template <typename TASK, typename ...ARGS>
concept runnable = 
    requires (TASK task, int n, ARGS... args)  
    { 
        task (n, args...); 
        requires (sizeof...(args)==2);
    };

template <typename TASK, typename ...ARGS>
requires runnable<TASK, ARGS...>
void run (ARGS... args)
{
    TASK task; 
    auto fct = [&] (auto&&... params)  {  return task (123, params...); };
    std::apply (fct, std::tuple<ARGS...> {args...});
}

struct MyTask1  {  int operator() (int n, std::string s, double x) const { return 0; }  };
struct MyTask2  {  int operator() (       std::string s, double x) const { return 0; }  };
struct MyTask3  {  int operator() (int n, std::string s)           const { return 0; }  };
```

Now, some examples of use:

1. `int main ()  {  run<MyTask1> (std::string("foo"), 3.14);  }` will compile with no error
2. `int main ()  {  run<MyTask2> (std::string("foo"), 3.14);  }` will not compile because of the first constraint of the concept, ie. the first parameter of `MyTask2::operator()` is not an int
3. `int main ()  {  run<MyTask3> (std::string("foo"));  }` will not compile because of the constraint `sizeof...(args)==2`

**Remark**: if I remove the usage of the `runnable` concept in the definition of `run`, there is also an error with `MyTask2` because there is no matching candidate for the call `task(123, params...)`. However, the error message is less readable than when the concept is used, which seems to be one of the strengths of the concept idea after all.